# Idiomatic method of parsing swift(3) data streams

Tags: swift

I'm trying to do some simple BSON parsing of Swift3 Data objects. I feel like I'm fighting the system.

Let's start with some input and a scheme:

```
let input = Data(bytes: [2, 0x20, 0x21, 3, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 1, 0x10, 4, 0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43])
```

This is just a simple data stream, the frivolous scheme being that a leading byte indicates how many bytes follow making up the next chunk. So in the above, the leading 2 indicates that 0x20, 0x21 are the first chunk, followed by a 3 byte chunk containing the bytes 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, etc.

**Streams**

My first thought is to do it with a stream (er, Generator, Iterator, whatever). So I end up with something like:

```
var iter = input.makeIterator()

func parse(_ stream:inout IndexingIterator<Data>) -> Data {
    var result = Data()
    if let count = stream.next() {
        for _ in 0..<count {
            result.append(Data(bytes:[stream.next()!]))
        }
    }
    return result
}

parse(&iter)
parse(&iter)
parse(&iter)
parse(&iter)
```

This leads to multiple questions/observations:

1) Why would anyone ever `let` an iterator? The whole point of this thing is to keep track of an evolving position over a collection. I really struggle with why the Swift authors have chosen to send iterators down the "all hail the value semantics" rathole. It means I have to put `inout`'s on all my parse functions.

2) I feel like I'm over-specifying the argument type with IndexingIterator. Maybe I just need to get used to verbose generics?

**Python Struct'esque**

Frustrated with that approach, I thought I might emulate pythons struct.unpack() style, where a tuple is returned of the parsed data, as well as the unconsumed data. Since supposedly Data are magical and efficient as long as I don't mutate them. That turned up like:

```
func parse2(_ data:Data) -> (Data, Data) {
    let count = Int(data[0])
    return (data.subdata(in: 1..<count+1), data.subdata(in: count+1..<data.count))
}

var remaining = input
var chunk = Data()
(chunk, rest) = parse2(remaining)
chunk
(chunk, rest) = parse2(remaining)
chunk
(chunk, rest) = parse2(remaining)
chunk
(chunk, rest) = parse2(remaining)
chunk
```

I ran into two issues with this.

1) What I really wanted to return was `data[1..count], data.subdata(in: count+1..<data.count)`. But this returns a MutableRandomAccessSlice. Which seems to be a totally different kind of type? So I ended up using the more involved `subdata`.

2) One can subscript a Data with a closed range, but the `subdata` method will only take an open range. What's with that?

**Open Rebellion, Old Habits Kick In**

Now annoyed that this old Smalltalker can't seem to find happiness here, I just roll my own:

```
class DataStream {
    let data:Data
    var index = 0
    var atEnd:Bool {
        return index >= self.data.count
    }

    init(data:Data) {
        self.data = data
    }

    func next() -> UInt8 {
        let byte = self.data[self.index]
        self.index += 1
        return byte
    }

    func next(_ count:Int) -> Data {
        let subdata = self.data.subdata(in: self.index..<self.index + count)
        self.index += count
        return subdata
    }

}

func parse3(_ stream:DataStream) -> Data {
    let count = Int(stream.next())
    return stream.next(count)
}

let stream = DataStream(data: input)
parse3(stream)
parse3(stream)
parse3(stream)
parse3(stream)
```

This solution I'm happy with from an end use POV. I can flesh out DataStream to do all kinds of stuff. But... I'm now off the beaten path and feel like I'm not "getting it" (the Swiftish light bulb).

**TL;DR version**

After this playing around, I find myself curious what the most idiomatic way to stream through Data structs, extracting data from them, based on what is encountered in them.

Comment: for #2 you can use a type alias

Comment: I can see your frustration but Xcode 8 is still in beta. Swift 2 wasn't super stable until Xcode 7 Beta 4 or 5

Comment: @CodeDifferent I'm not sure this has much to do with xcode8 or swift3, other than the assumed direction being to use  `Data` preferentially over `[UInt8]`s going forward. A primary contributing factor of my frustration is why Iterators are better as value type structs instead of reference type objects.

Comment: Another option would be to create an [InputStream](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsinputstream) from the data and then use the streams read method. –  But your DataStream is also a good approach. I would change some details, like checking if sufficient data is available and return `nil` otherwise.

Comment: Wish your comment was in answer form @MartinR; DataStream with your suggestions was the solution I ended up using and have been happy with.

Comment: @TravisGriggs: I suggest that you post a self-answer with your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, as mentioned in the comments, I went with a `DataStream` class including suggestions by MartinR. Here's the implementation I'm using today.

```
class DataStream {
    let data:Data
    var index = 0
    var atEnd:Bool {
        return index >= self.data.count
    }

    init(data:Data) {
        self.data = data
    }

    func next() -> UInt8? {
        guard self.atEnd.NOT else { return nil }
        let byte = self.data[self.index]
        self.index += 1
        return byte
    }

    func next(_ count:Int) -> Data? {
        guard self.index + count <= self.data.count else { return nil }
        let subdata = self.data.subdata(in: self.index..<self.index + count)
        self.index += count
        return subdata
    }

    func upTo(_ marker:UInt8) -> Data? {
        if let end = (self.index..<self.data.count).index( where: { self.data[$0] == marker } ) {
            let upTo = self.next(end - self.index)
            self.skip() // consume the marker
            return upTo
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func skip(_ count:Int = 1) {
        self.index += count
    }

    func skipThrough(_ marker:UInt8) {
        if let end = (self.index..<self.data.count).index( where: { self.data[$0] == marker } ) {
            self.index = end + 1
        }
        else {
            self.index = self.data.count
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Disclaimer: I realize upon reading the OP:s question again (not just the using TL;DR eyes ;) that this don't really answer the OP:s question, but I'll leave it as it might make a somewhat interesting addition to the discussion; `split` don't produce a stream here, but rather a chunk of data sequences)*

This is somewhat similar to your *"Python Struct'esque"* solution; you could make use the `isSeparator` predicate closure of the `split` method of `Data` to parse your byte stream.

> ```
> func split(maxSplits: Int = default, omittingEmptySubsequences: Bool = default, 
>            isSeparator: @noescape UInt8 throws -> Bool) 
>            rethrows -> [MutableRandomAccessSlice<Data>]
> ```
>
> Returns the longest possible subsequences of the sequence, in order,
>   that don’t contain elements satisfying the given predicate. Elements
>   that are used to split the sequence are not returned as part of any
>   subsequence.

From [The Language Reference for the `Data` structure (Swift 3)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1779631-split).

I haven't had time to download XCode 8 beta myself (and IBM Swift 3-dec Sandbox does not include the `Data` structure, for some reason), but an example of using `split(...)` (here: just for an array) could look something along the lines of:

```
/* Swift 2.2 example */
let input: [UInt8] = [2, 0x20, 0x21, 3, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 1, 0x10, 4, 0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43]

var isSep = true
var byteCounter: (UInt8, UInt8) = (0,0)
let parsed = input.split() { elem -> Bool in
    if isSep {
        isSep = false
        byteCounter.0 = 0
        byteCounter.1 = elem
        return true
    }

    byteCounter.0 += 1
    if byteCounter.0 == byteCounter.1 {
        isSep = true // next is separator
    }
    return false

}.map { Array($0) }

print(parsed) // [[32, 33], [48, 49, 50], [16], [64, 65, 66, 67]]
```

A non-tested equivalent snippet for the Swift 3 `Data` structure:

```
let input = Data(bytes: [2, 0x20, 0x21, 3, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 1, 0x10, 4, 0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43])

var isSep = true
var byteCounter: (UInt8, UInt8) = (0,0)
let parsed = input.split(maxSplits: 1000, omittingEmptySubsequences: false) { elem -> Bool in
    if isSep {
        isSep = false
        byteCounter.0 = 0
        byteCounter.1 = elem
        return true
    }
    byteCounter.0 += 1
    if byteCounter.0 == byteCounter.1 {
        isSep = true // next is separator
    }
    return false
}.map { $0 }
```

Note that `MutableRandomAccessSlice<Data>` should be "trivially" transformable to `Data` (`Data` itself is a `MutableCollection` of bytes), compare e.g. to the simple map over self to transform `ArraySlice<Int>` to `Array<Int>`

```
let foo = [1, 2, 3]
let bar = foo[0..<2]     // ArraySlice<Int>
let baz = bar.map { $0 } // Array<Int>
```